# MongoDB $project for field with spaces in the name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document that goes like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(111603),
    "max" : "Created At",
    "document" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54ad61013e016de5798c0582"),
        "testfield1" : "ISUZU (GM)",
        "Model - Range" : "N-series",
        "testfield2" : "N NQR 75",
    }
}
```

And I would like to aggregate on the collection containing a number of these documents. I'm having an issue with the "Model - Range" in the $project step.
Currently I am using

```js
db.AE.aggregate([
    {"$project":{
        "Make":"$document.testfield1",
        "Model":"$document.testfield2",
        "_id":0, 
        "Group": "$document['Model - Range']"
     }}
]);
```

But for some reason, MongoDB is completely ignoring the Group field and only adding the other two fields.

Is there a way to address fields with spaces/special characters in them when projecting in MongoDB aggregation framework?

Comment: Yes it's not a valid way to notate this ( it is a string and not JavaScript code you did notice ) and you really should not name fields like this. Windows taught too many of the younger generation very bad habits. We code and model with `consecutiveCamelCasedNames` because we have experience and we know what works and what does not.

Comment: What if I have no control over the field names, based on the mongoDB documentation, the only characters that are not accepted are "." and ones that start with "$".

Comment: It got answered. I didn't want to because you really should not name properties this way. It only results in someone coming in and fixing your code. Leave a better legacy on the world and do it right the first time.

Comment: The fields get created by an external CSV file that I do not control. The entire idea of a noSQL database is that everything should be variable..types, names, etc.. I agree that naming conventions should exist even in noSQL but in this particular case the only way to do it is to re-adjust the field names while importing (again sort of defies the idea behind noSQL)

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you though, I will try to keep that in mind.

Comment: You know you can always "map" field names in CSV imports. So there is that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use normal dot notation for that field:

```js
db.AE.aggregate([
    {"$project":{
        "Make":"$document.testfield1",
        "Model":"$document.testfield2",
        "_id":0, 
        "Group": "$document.Model - Range"
     }}
]);
```

But I agree with Neil that field names with spaces in them should be avoided, if possible.